# Using momentjs with correct locale in React server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, isomorphic-javascript

I'm using React with server-side rendering.

I'm currently working on the display of date using `momentjs.fromNow()` which should display things like "two minutes ago" etc. It works fine on the browser (with language change), but the code returned by the server is in english, when the language of the browser is french.

I know I can change the locale of moment using moment.locale('fr-FR'), but I suspect that server side this will change the locale of moment for all use of moment, and as the rendering is async, if two users with different locales access near the same time the server, it might cause conflicts.

Is there a way to specify moment's locale for this current rendering only ?

Comment: You can specify this as last client script that will override the server setting of the momentjs locale. Have you tried this?

Comment: I don't get what you suggest ? What should I specify in the last script ? I want to be able to specify the moment locale for all calls to moment in the ReactDomServer.renderToString method.  Hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
import 'moment/locale/fr';
```

Comment: It will be better if add some example code

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Also, you should check how to format your posts properly here 
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code